# jQuery set option in dynamic select

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using jQuery v1.10.2.

I've a select wich will be filled dynamicly by ajax:

```
<select id="mySelect"></select>
```

I'm trying to set an option in a nother ajax call:

```
function GetValues(id) {
    LoadSelectOptions('#mySelect');
    /* select has now following options:
        <option value="0"></option>
        <option value="1">Test 1</option> */
    $.ajax({
        ..
        success: function (data) {
            $('#mySelect').val(data.value); // data.value = 1
        },
        ..
    });
}
```

This code
    $('#mySelect').val(data.value);
in my success area of the ajax call don't sets the option to "Test 1". I've also tried to do following:

```
$('#mySelect').val(data.value).change();
$('#mySelect option[value="' + data.value + '"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
$('#mySelect option[value="' + data.value + '"]').attr('selected', true);
$('#mySelect option[value="' + data.value + '"]').prop('selected', 'selected');
$('#mySelect option[value="' + data.value + '"]').prop('selected', true);
```

But nothing works in Chrome + Firefox (both latest version).

Thanks for help :)

Comment: yes .. I'm sure that data.value is 1

Comment: try setting the val in the ajax complete method.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :-

```
$("select#mySelect").val(data.value);
```

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/E5BBx/)

Comment: this wont work, cause it has to do with ajax, complete method is the only way to ensure you have the response completely available specially when request is asynchronous, else best way is to have a callback function in success and execute it with the response obtained.